# How to concatenate a row vector with itself in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have a row vector of size <1x12582 cell>, and I want to combine it with itself to get as a result <1x25164 cell>. For example:

```
cellint = {'gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4'};

cellout = {'gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4','gene1','gene2','gene3','gene4'};
```

I have tried `horzcat` as follows, but it didn't give the correct result:

```
SS = [cellint;cellint];
```

Comment: `[cellint; cellint]` works for me. Also `vertcat(cellint, cellint)` or `repmat(cellint,2,1)`. Your text says a row vector, but your example variables and desired result are column vectors

Comment: @Luis Mendo Friend so sorry, it is a row vector, i have edited the format.

Comment: `cellout = [cellint cellint];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Horizontal concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/horzcat.html) (i.e. concatenation along the second (column) dimension) uses spaces or commas within square brackets:

```
cellout = [cellint cellint];          % or ...
cellout = [cellint, cellint];         % or ...

% Functional equivalents:
cellout = horzcat(cellint, cellint);  % or ...
cellout = cat(2, cellint, cellint);
```

[Vertical concatenation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html) (i.e. concatenation along the first (row) dimension) uses semicolons within square brackets:

```
cellout = [cellint; cellint];         % or ...

% Functional equivalents:
cellout = vertcat(cellint, cellint);  % or ...
cellout = cat(1, cellint, cellint);
```

For concatenation along an arbitrary dimension (as illustrated in the last line of each example above), use the function [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html):

```
cellout = cat(3, cellint, cellint);  % Would concatenate along the third dimension
```